# How do I stop the file directory printing in my debug terminal every time I run debug?

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging, terminal, launch

I'm using visual studio code running Python 3 and every time I run debug in the terminal window it shows my entire file directory for the current .py file I'm working on. Here's an example:

```
Maxs-MBP:Exercise Files maxcalcroft$ cd "/Users/maxcalcroft/Desktop/Exercise Files" ; 
env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" python 
/Users/maxcalcroft/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.6.0/pythonFiles/PythonTools/visualstudio_py_launcher.py 
"/Users/maxcalcroft/Desktop/Exercise Files" 52452 34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14 RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput 
"/Users/maxcalcroft/Desktop/Exercise Files/Chap01/hello-working.py"

Hello, World.
Maxs-MBP:Exercise Files maxcalcroft$
```

This was just a simple print "Hello, World." command yet I get all this extra directory stuff.

One answer I saw showed going into the launch.json file and amending the `cwd` but there's not an option for me to change that in my launch.json file.

Comment: Is there any practical purpose of doing this ?

Comment: No not really, it just makes it easier for me from an aesthetic and readability point of view

Comment: Having the exact command used to run things, in easy copy-passable form, can be useful information if, e.g., you need to reproduce the same test with a different Python installation, or explain some weird behavior in a Stack Overflow question. When it’s not needed, it’s ugly. And I can understand why you might want to disable it by default (you can always turn it back on when you need it, right?), so this isn’t an answer; I’m just pointing out that debuggers naturally tend to err on the side of too much ugliness by default rather than too little.

Comment: @abarnert Ah ok thanks. Might just have to keep it then.

Comment: As I said, I can understand why you might not want to see it most of the time–and, as long as you know how to turn it back on when you _do_ need it, there's no reason you can't turn it off. (Well, except that VSCode might not have a way to turn it off; I don't know whether it does…)

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the tag `visual-studio` is only for Visual Studio, not for Visual Studio Code, which, despite the confusing naming, is an entirely separate and very different program, which I'd guess has its own tag (maybe `visual-studio-code` or `vscode`? but you can search for it as easily as I can…).